# android settext only if it starts with

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner, decoder

i have a android phone with a build in rfid scanner for barcodes which and i wonder if there some how a way i can get this scanner to only paste the decoderesult to 
    `cardnumberbox` only if it starts with a `K`
    otherwise only paste it to `shelfnumberbox` if it starts with an `R`

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    HashMap<String, String> result = (HashMap<String, String>) msg.obj;
    switch (msg.what) {
        case GET_CODE_CASE:
            if (!isScanTimeOut()) {
                cardnumberbox.setText(result.get("decodeResult"));
            } else {
                if (toast != null) toast.cancel();
                toast = Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, R.string.try_again,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
            scanCase = 0;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
};
```

Comment: have you tried checking is string starts from K?

Comment: please check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find information like this yourself if you have sources installed and simply look at the classes (in this case the string class)

```
String decoderesult = result.get("decodeResult");
if (decoderesult.toLowerCase().startsWith("k")) {
    cardnumberbox.setText(decoderesult);
} else if (decoderesult.toLowerCase().startsWith("r")) {
    shelfnumberbox.setText(decoderesult);
}
```

Comment: awesome that did the trick i had tryed out with a textwatcher but that didn't worked for pasteing